# Should we put the commit higher or lower while rebasing if we want to push only it?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-push

I have pulled the master branch. In the local master I have made several commits. Now I want to push only the last commit (and not the previous ones). How do I achieve this?

I found a good explanation of how to do it: [How to push only one commit with Git](http://blog.dennisrobinson.name/push-only-one-commit-with-git/). So, the command should be something like this:

```
git push origin 2dc2b7e393e6b712ef103eaac81050b9693395a4:master
```

Or, in a more "abstract" form:

```
git push <remote name> <commit hash>:<remote branch name>
```

However, as far as I understood, in a general case, it will **not** push the single commit (given by its hash). Instead, it will push the specified commit as well as all commits that have been done before the specified commit.

So, to achieve the goal (pushing only one single commit) we need first to reorder the commits such that the commit that we want to push is see as the oldest one (the first one in the sequence of the commits). How to do it is described here: [How to reorder commits with Git](http://blog.dennisrobinson.name/reorder-commits-with-git/). This description is clear, the only thing that confuses me is this phrase:

> In my case, I wanted to bring my top most commit where I fixed the
>   project file down to the bottom so that I can push only that one
>   commit to the remote server.

But isn't it the case that we want to do a kind of opposite? If we bring the commit "down to the bottom", it will be considered as the last (most recent) commit and if we use its hash when we push, we will push everything that comes before it (which means "all commits").

So, what we want to do is to put our commit higher in the file that we see when we execute `git rebase -i HEAD~5`. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to push only one commit `cfoo` to a branch `bbar`, here's a simple solution:

```
git fetch origin bbar
git checkout FETCH_HEAD
git cherry-pick cfoo
git push origin HEAD:bbar
```

In a real case, you may need to run `git stash` or do something else to backup the workaround.

As for "higher", yes, in the text editor that pops up after `git rebase -i`, the first line is the oldest commit. If you'd like to push only one commit, then put it in the first line.

Comment: But what if I do not pull from the repository to which I push?

Comment: @Roman it doesn't matter. You can specify the url dynamically of the remote repository when run `git push` or `git pull`(including `git fetch`). `git push <urlA> HEAD:<branchA>`, `git pull <urlB> <branchB>`, where `branchA` and `branchB` can have the same name. If `urlA` and `urlB` are constant, you can add them as one or two remotes. One remote has two values, one for push and the other for fetch.

Comment: @Roman your approach is okay if you don't mind that the history of the local branch is changed by `git rebase -i`.

Comment: yes, I do not mind that the history is changed. The only problem that I have is that I do not know where to put my commit (the one that I want to push) in the list of the commits. I think it should be put higher but in the article that I have linked it is said that I need to put it to the very button. So, I am confused.

Comment: @Roman by "higher" if you mean "closer to the tip of the branch", it should be as far away from the tip as possible where the remote branch has contained the commit of its parent. As you mentioned, when you push a commit, all of its ancestors will be pushed too. If the remote branch has had all of its ancestors, then it's the only one that will be pushed.

Comment: by "higher" I mean closer to the first line of the file that I see in the text editor. Which also mean "closer to the tip of the branch". As far as I understand it should be directly after the tip of the branch (so, on next line). So, it should be as close as possible to the tip of the branch. So that this commit is seen as the oldest one (among those that are not pushed yet). Why do you write that it should be "as far away from tip as possible". Shouldn't it it be "as close as possible"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161704/discussion-between-elpiekay-and-roman).